# Why bash has error in $(cat $DIST_ROOT/build_env/build_env_list)

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I try to create directory but i have this error

```
preapare.sh: stroke 6: /home/lld/LLD_linux_dist/build_env/build_env_list: No such file or directary
```

Code:

```
echo "Dist Root: ${DIST_ROOT:?}"
echo "LFS: ${LFS:?}"

mkdir -p $LFS/sources

for f in $($DIST_ROOT/build_env/build_env_list)
do
    echo $f
done;
```

Screen-shot of file directory

[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo9XH.png)

I tried to change something but nothing helped maybe some one knows how to fix it (Fedora,VsCode)

Comment: What do you think that code is supposed to do? It's obviously wrong, to us as human readers just as it is to the interpreter, but what's not obvious to anyone but you is what it's _supposed_ to mean in your head, and if we don't know that, we can't tell you what a corrected version would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Typically what you put inside `$()` is a command.
If `build_env_list` is a directory, replace the `for` line with:

```
for f in $DIST_ROOT/build_env/build_env_list/*
```

Now, if `build_env_list` is a file containing a list of files, then you may replace this line with:

```
for f in $(cat $DIST_ROOT/build_env/build_env_list)
```